# Loop for-each in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm new to Scheme...

can someone please explain for me why the for-each statement doesn't print out the output??

I have a graph defined:

```
(define graph '((a (b.c)) (c (d))))
```

and my test code:

```
(define testing
  (lambda (a-list)
    (if (null? a-list)
        "size = 0"
        (for-each (lambda (i)
                   (cons (car i) (length (cdr i)))
                   (length a-list)) 
                  a-list))))
```

when run this `(testing graph)`, output expected is `((a . 2) (c . 1))` but it display nothing...

Answer (score 4):

The [`for-each`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._for-each%29%29) procedure doesn't build a list as output, it just executes a procedure on each of the input list's elements. You're looking for [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/map..rkt%29._map%29%29), which creates a new list with the result of applying a function to each of the elements in the input list. Also notice that there are bugs in your code regarding the creation/traversal of the graph. This should fix the problems:

```
(define graph
  '((a (b c)) ; fixed a bug here
    (c (d))))

(define testing
  (lambda (a-list)
    (if (null? a-list)
        "size = 0"
        (map (lambda (i)
               (cons (car i) (length (cadr i)))) ; fixed a bug here
             a-list))))
```

Now it works as expected:

```
(display (testing graph))
=> '((a . 2) (c . 1))
```

Comment: To be accurate the correct way to get it **displayed** would be `(display (testing graph))`. (eg. `#!r6rs` in DrRacket where it doesn't display any result when running `(test graph)` in the definitions windows)